# Extra space at bottom of page caused by “cye-workaround-body” and “cye-workaround-body-image” divs in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For some reason, there are two `div`'s with the ID's “cye-workaround-body” and “cye-workaround-body-image” which which get added below the `</body>` of some websites and it creates a large space beneath the footer. As far as I can tell this only happens in Google Chrome.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Is it safe to remove these `div`'s?

How would I go about preventing this from happening?

[Here is an example](https://www.v9seo.com/blog/2015/05/19/wordpress-vs-joomla-right-for-my-site/)
 and 
[Another Example](http://blog.bluehost.com./blog/wordpress-2/building-a-better-website-with-wordpress-themes-858/)

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting issue. When you say "some websites", do you mean some websites on the internet at large? What are a few of the ones you've come across?

Comment: I first noticed it with a few of my own websites. But it also happens in the 'wild'. I updated the question with two random links

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit: @Kbam7 has confirmed that the problem lies in an extension called "Care your Eyes", hence the "cye" divs. To fix this problem, disable or remove the extension.**

---

Original Answer:

I'm not seeing divs with `cye-workaround-body` or `cye-workaround-body-image` in either of the sites you linked. This leads me to believe that it might be caused by a Chrome extension that you have installed.

Make sure none of your extensions are set to run in incognito mode, then try visiting those URLs in incognito mode and see if the problem persists. Also, please try visiting those sites using Chrome on a different computer. If you realize that it is working in either of those two circumstances, then you can start disabling extensions until you narrow down which extension is causing those extra elements to be added.

As an aside, it looks like [nobody else is having the same issue](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%22cye-workaround-body%22) (google results showed this thread only at the time of writing), so that lends further evidence towards my hunch that this is not a problem in vanilla Chrome.

Comment: Hmm, okay it seems you're right. It seems to be one of my extensions. I cant believe i did not think of that! Thank you good sir!

Comment: To be precise its an extension called : Care your Eyes - hence the "cye". Thanks again! You have put my mind at ease. :)

Comment: @Kbam7 Good to know! That will also help future visitors find this in Google search. Thanks!